# Regex: match a string if the next 5 characters contain 3 occurences ot the character k

Tags: regex

I like to match all substrings in a continues string, which start with a specific character and are followed by 5 arbitrary characters, which at least contain the character c 3 times.

Every String I am looking for has some arbitrary characters (x) and the starting character I am looking for (M) and I only what to match the String if the next 5 characters contain exactly C 3 times.

e.g.:

1. ...xxMxCxCCxCxC...
2. ...xxMCCCxxCxxC...
3. ...xxMCxxxCCxxC...
4. ...xxMxCCCCxCxx...

returning:

1. MxCxCC
2. MCCCxx
3. Null --> only 2x C in 5 characters after M
4. Null --> 4x C in the 5 characters after M

*Case is not important I just used upper case for better illustration*

I tried several things but the closest I got was, to be able to match everything until 3x C were reached:

```
   M(?:[^C]*C){3}
```

and i was wondering, if I could somehow combine this with a Lookahead.

I am fairly new to this so maybe you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you might also match M followed by 5 times a non whitespace char.

Then use a positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is M followed by matching 3 times a C, and 0-2 times any char except C

```
M\S{5}(?<=M(?:[^C\s]{0,3}C){3}[^C\s]{0,2})
```

**Explanation**

- `M` Match M
- `\S{5}` Match 5 times a non whitespace char
- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `M` Match M
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^C\s]{0,3}C` Match 0-3 times any char except C or whitespace char, then match C
  - `){3}` Close group and repeat 3 times
  - `[^C\s]{0,2}` Match 0-2 times any char except C or whitespace char
- `)` Close lookbehind

Instead of using `\S`, you could also use `[A-Za-z]{5}` to match only chars a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oTJep5/1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to enumerate the 10 possible ways `C` may appear exactly 3 times in a string of five characters:

```
M(?:C{3}[^C]{2}|C{2}[^C]C[^C]|C{2}[^C]{2}C|C[^C]C{2}[^C]|C[^C]C[^C]C|C[^C]{2}C{2}|[^C]C{3}[^C]|[^C]C{2}[^C]C|[^C]C[^C]C{2}|[^C]{2}C{3})
```

The case-different flag needs to be set (`/i` or add `(?i)` at the beginning).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNT9Af/1/)

The regex can be read more easily as follows.

```
M
(?:
  C{3}[^C]{2}
  |
  C{2}[^C]C[^C]
  |
  C{2}[^C]{2}C
  |
  C[^C]C{2}[^C]
  |
  C[^C]C[^C]C
  |
  C[^C]{2}C{2}
  |
  [^C]C{3}[^C]
  |
  [^C]C{2}[^C]C
  |
  [^C]C[^C]C{2}
  |
  [^C]{2}C{3} 
)
```

I used the following Ruby code to get the 10 combinations (to make sure I didn't miss any):

```
['C','[^C]'].repeated_permutation(5)
            .select { |arr| arr.count('C') == 3 }
```